# Apps don't work with IPv6 enabled in router

Tags: applications, wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, networking, connection-issues

So I've been having this issue for a while now where apps work fine over mobile data won't work when mobile is connected to otherwise perfectly working WiFi.
Some such apps are-

- Discord (keeps on connecting and asks to check server)
- Spotify  (keeps on loading)
- twitter  (continuously loads)
- google keyboard gif search tool while using WhatsApp (No gif preview and unable to send them.)

I'd like to mention that the same apps work great on other devices over the same wifi. I made a thread about it last week -

[Here's my post on XDA which temporarily solved this issue](https://forum.xda-developers.com/general/networking/apps-fine-mobile-data-wont-wifi-t3959012)

The temporary solution that doesn't work anymore was clearing phones cache and putting it on airplane mode.
Now I found a way with which I was able to replicate this 'bug'. Turning IPv6 off in my wifi settings. It worked, for now at least.

[Using this guide's 11th given solution fixed my problem for now.](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ambassador-guides-tips-how-tos/326698-guide-troubleshooting-wi-fi-connection-problems.html)

~So do I keep the IPv6 off without any consequences or is there a workaround cause from what I know IPv6 is important and it should be on.
Is there a better, more concrete solution?

Device-Xiaomi's Redmi Note 3-Kenzo
Root- No
OEM- Unlocked

Comment: Do you receive v6 IP address at router from your ISP? And does router assign your phone an IPv6 (through DHCP6 or SLAAC)? If no, then disabling IPv6 on router as well on phone is a wise decision.

Comment: @IrfanLatif is there a way to check the above mentioned? Cause I am not sure about either of these.

Comment: Use `ip a` on phone, see router's obtained IP in admin panel. Or visit https://ipv6-test.com/.

Comment: @IrfanLatif Upon enabling IPv6 from the router settings and running the test on my mobile, the results state that IPv6 is not supported. So does it mean the problem is on the ISP side?

Comment: It's not a "problem" as such, it's expected. Not every ISP is [IPv6-ready](http://ipv6forum.com/ipv6_enabled/isp/approval_list.php) and even if they are, every consumer might not get IPv6 address immediately. The details must be in your contract with the ISP. Or you may ask them if they provide IPv6 service and if the router is capable of handling IPv6 routing things.

Comment: Well if it's not a 'problem' and/ or doesn't hinder any of my abilities on the internet should I just keep on going with IPv6 switched off?

Comment: If you don't already know what capabilities you lack due to not having a v6 IP address, then you certainly don't need those capabilities. Keeping IPv6 off won't do any harm to you. With root you can switch that off on Android device too.

Comment: I mean, not being able to use important apps over wifi in itself is hindering my internet access isn't it? But if that's all and I will not Miss out on anything else then I guess I'll keep it off and just move on.

Comment: May be the router is assigning your phone an IPv6 and some of the apps try to connect to internet over IPv6. But router doesn't have IPv6 from ISP, so you face the hindrance. Will have to troubleshoot in depth to identify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Solution- Keep IPv6 turned off.
Reason- ISP not providing IPv6 connection so while it's on in the router settings it somehow stops my access to certain apps only on my redmi note 3. 
Yeah IDK but it's good enough for me.